# Join Multiline stack into 1 line

Tags: shell

I would like to convert the following log stack into a single line while keeping separation between the two stacks.

My question is what is the Linux command to achieve the desired output below based on the sample log?

Sample log:

```
At 2014-12-24 10:45:40.010: 250 OK^M
At 2014-12-24 10:45:40.010: 550 Unknown user^M
At 2014-12-24 10:45:40.010: 503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:^M
503-Unknown user^M
503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA^M
Log-Entry-Offset/Size: 1267870/0000633^M
Content-ID: 223994/50022_2142272156   HU^M
MailHost: btinternet.com(0.0.0.0)^M
Addressee: denniscruze@btinternet.com^M
Status-Attempt-Session-Error: 55:1:39d9:451^M
Date: Wed Dec 24 10:45:40 EST 2014^M
At 2014-12-24 10:45:39.846: Sent: RSET^M

At 2014-12-24 10:46:09.658: 250 OK^M
At 2014-12-24 10:46:09.658: 550 Unknown user^M
At 2014-12-24 10:46:09.658: 503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:^M
503-Unknown user^M
503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA^M
Log-Entry-Offset/Size: 2705117/0000659^M
Content-ID: 16680/50022_1962750881   HU^M
MailHost: aol.com(0.0.0.0)^M
Addressee: mvrow@aol.com^M
Status-Attempt-Session-Error: 1:1:39a2:250^M
Date: Wed Dec 24 10:46:09 EST 2014^M
At 2014-12-24 10:46:09.498: Sent: MAIL FROM:<news@go.intervalworld.com>^M
```

Desired Output:

```
At 2014-12-24 10:45:40.010: 250 OK^M At 2014-12-24 10:45:40.010: 550 Unknown user^M At 2014-12-24 10:45:40.010: 503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:^M 503-Unknown user^M 503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA^M Log-Entry-Offset/Size: 1267870/0000633^M Content-ID: 223994/50022_2142272156   HU^M MailHost: btinternet.com(0.0.0.0)^M Addressee: denniscruze@btinternet.com^M Status-Attempt-Session-Error: 55:1:39d9:451^M Date: Wed Dec 24 10:45:40 EST 2014^M At 2014-12-24 10:45:39.846: Sent: RSET^M

At 2014-12-24 10:46:09.658: 250 OK^M At 2014-12-24 10:46:09.658: 550 Unknown user^M At 2014-12-24 10:46:09.658: 503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:^M 503-Unknown user^M 503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA^M Log-Entry-Offset/Size: 2705117/0000659^M Content-ID: 16680/50022_1962750881   HU^M MailHost: aol.com(0.0.0.0)^M Addressee: mvrow@aol.com^M Status-Attempt-Session-Error: 1:1:39a2:250^M Date: Wed Dec 24 10:46:09 EST 2014^M At 2014-12-24 10:46:09.498: Sent: MAIL FROM:<news@go.intervalworld.com>^M
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is what is the Linux command to achieve the desired output above based on the sample log?

Comment: Sounds good! Never forget to actually put the question in your post (and you should edit your post now to include that).

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS='\n'
    RS='\n\n'
}
{
    gsub(/\n/, " ", $0)
    print $0
    print ""
}' file_goes_here
```

Seperate the file record per record, i.e. all the stuff you want next to each other, they are separated bij double newlines. Then sub all newlines for spaces and output.